# Scala - How to create a combine ArrayList of functions with and without parameters

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism

Suppose I have to following:

```
def f1: Int ( or  def f1(): Int )
def f2 (x: Int): Int
def f3 (x: Int): Int
def f4: Int
...
...
```

note: 'Int' here is just an example

I would like to do ....

```
class Container[T] {
  val values = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[T => Int]
  def addValue(value: T => Int) = values += v
  def doSome(t: T): Int = values.foldLeft[Int](0){ (complete, v) => complete + v(t) }
}

val ContainerWithParam = new Container[Int]
val ContainerWithoutParam = new Container[???]

ContainerWithParam.addValue(f2)
ContainerWithoutParam.addValue(f1)

val result = ContainerWithParam.doSome(1000) + ContainerWithoutParam.doSome(???)
```

One solution is to use Option[Nothing]

```
class Container[T] {
  val values = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[T => Int]
  def addValue(value: T => Int) = values += v
  def doSome(t: T): Int = values.foldLeft[Int](0){ (complete, v) => complete + v(t) }
}

def f1(nothing: Option[Nothing]): Int
val ContainerWithoutParam = new Container[Option[Nothing]]
ContainerWithoutParam.doSome(None)
```

but I think this is not a very clean and nice code...

Answer (score 1):

If `def f1: Int = ???` then ...

```
val containerWithParam = new Container[Int]
val containerWithoutParam = new Container[Unit]

containerWithParam.addValue(f2)
containerWithoutParam.addValue(_ => f1)

val result = containerWithParam.doSome(1000) +
             containerWithoutParam.doSome(())
```

If `def f1(): Int = ???` then `.addValue(_ => f1())`.

Comment: You can use `Function.const(f1())` instead of `_ => f1()`. It's mostly a matter of taste, but I find it a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @jwvh is right, but as an alternative you can create a separate class for the case where the function does not have a parameter. This can re-use the original implementation.

```
class ContainerNoParam {
  private val container = new Container[Unit];
  def addValue(value: => Int): Unit = container.addValue(_ => value)
  def doSome(): Int = container.doSome(())
}

val ContainerWithParam = new Container[Int]
val ContainerWithoutParam = new ContainerNoParam

ContainerWithParam.addValue(f2)
ContainerWithoutParam.addValue(f1)

val result = ContainerWithParam.doSome(1000) + ContainerWithoutParam.doSome()
```